# E-Mail notifications only work for first e-mail account (GMail)?

Tags: email, notifications, apns, mobile-mail

Currently I finally - way too late - noticed that still in iOS 6, the Apple Mail app is not sending me push notifications - or any notifications for that matter - for any of my e-mail accounts except the first one, which happens to be my GMail account.

The other ones (of 6 total) are: Another GMail account, a Nate(.com) & Daum(.net) account and two domain names I bought (one via GoogleApps, the other not).

My settings are: Push and "Fetch every 15 minutes", with Fetch activated for all email accounts named above.

So as I get no notifications (and thus today missed an important e-mail in the afternoon, even though I kept an eye on my phone), I wonder how to troubleshoot this?

Finally I wonder why "push" is still not a reality? I mean in all my settings there is no "push" option, for whatever of the above accounts I use. Is "push" only possible when you have a Blackberry or Sharepoint or sth. ?

Comment: I can't answer your question but can tell you that push notification works for all my e-mail accounts (3). Push mail has to be offered by the services itself. It works for my exchange and Google Mail account (which I've configured to use Exchange instead of IMAP).

Answer (score 1):

I know push works for iCloud email accounts (@me.com), but as for the other ones, I'm not positive.

You can configure your email notifications by tapping Settings > Notifications > Mail. After you are there, you will notice a list of email accounts. It appears that you have to customize each individual mail account separately. Tap on a email account, and you can configure it to alert you exactly the way you desire to be notified.

You can also use VIPs (under the list of email accounts mentioned above, or accessed by by tapping the arrow to the right of the VIP mailbox just under All Inboxes in the Mail app) to customize notifications depending on if particular senders are consistently urgent.

Comment: But for me, not individual senders are urgent, but a whole mailbox/account OR senders that I don't know yet! And as said, I was already under Settings > Notifications etc., the problem is that Mail doesn't seem to be fetched (and I'm not notified) as I should be, as of my setting.

Comment: If you have notifications set up properly, then it will alert you as soon as it receives an email (which in this case would be every 15 minutes). I think whether or not Push works is more server side. It indicates in Settings, that it will move to Fetch if Push is not configured on the server.

Comment: Actually i saw now one time the e-mail notification I was waiting for. The problem is, they don't seem to stay in the notification window!! The get drowned out by more current e-mails? But how can I prioritize individual mailboxes(accounts) or senders as "VIP" in my notifications bar (to stay there)? It seems Apple didn't think about that!! -.-

Comment: That is a very interesting point. There is no way to prioritize, and keep some on top of the notification list. You can change it to show 10 items in the notification center, if that helps. If it were me, I would try to evaluate which email addresses get, or which VIPs send, the important mail, and then shut off the notifications for the other accounts. That might possibly help that flow. Again, there isn't a way to have some stay on top that I can think of. Btw, please don't forget to accept/upvote if this helps/answers your question.